# iikArAnthaH shabda declension of nalinI

Tags: sanskrit

I know that in Sanskrit, there is nadI shabda for IkArAnthaH. For the name, nalinI, which is also IkArAnthaH strIlinga, would the declensions be the following?

1st - {nalinI, nalinyau, nalinyaH},

2nd - {nalinIm, nalinyau, nalinIH},

3rd -{nalinyA, nalinIbhyAm, nalinIbhyaH},

4th - {nalinyai, nalinIbhyAm, nalinIbhyaH},

5th - {nalinyAh, nalinIbhyAm, nalinIbhyaH},

6th - {nalinyAh, nalinyoH, nalinInAm},

7th - {nalinyAm, nalinyoH, nalinIshu},

8th - {hey nalinI, hey nalinyau, hey nalinyaH}

I just want to make sure I am understanding the shabda correctly.

Comment: Pure Sanskrit Language questions are off topic.

Comment: I would argue it is on topic. Sanskrit declensions are fundamental to being able to decode Hindu scriptures, and as the Sanskrit SE is still not approved, this question, I believe, is fine here. Perhaps, later on, it can be migrated. Not to mention, this question can be referred by other people when there is a question regarding scriptures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nearly correct.

The incorrect ones are:

1. Singular of the Sambodhana-Prathama case (सम्बोधनप्रथमा विभक्ति: एकवचनम्) or the 8th case mentioned above. It should be 'hey nalini' (हे नलिनि) and not 'hey nalinI' (हे नलिनी).
2. Plural of the Tritiya case (त्रितीया विभक्ति: बहुवचनम्) or the 3rd case mentioned above. It should be 'nalinIbhih(नलिनीभि:)' and not 'nalinIbhyah(नलिनीभ्य:)'

The rest are good.

Comment: Good catch, I should have caught those mistakes! Thank you!